# Count the number of registration by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with a select I have to do, I have a data base where a new claim file is registered in the table called “claims”, in this table every file is registered as follows :

[image]

Sorry, i have attached above a print screen with how the tables look, i don't know why are as bellow when i post it.

```
ClaimFileNumber || Vehicle number || ……. || OpeningDate
1                  abc                      20170302
2                  bcd                      20170302
3                  efg                      20170301
4                  hij                      20170301
```

I need a select which can help me to find out how many claim files are open on each day from when this year started until now, ordered by top 5 days for each month like for example, on the month of May we have: 20170506 - 300 claims, 20170511 – 295 claims, 20170509 – 200 claims etc.
Or it is ok a select which can give me the number of claims opened per day and order them desc.

The problem is that the date stored in table OpeningDate it is stored as numeric and not as date, this is the tricky part at least for me.

I cannot use a select like “select count (OpeningDate) from claim where openingdate = 20170302” for each day because there are more than 200 days from when the year have started.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Tip of today: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You say you want to know "how many claim files are open on each day", but I supposed you rather mean claim files are open**ed** on a day? Otherwise you'd have to tell us how long opened claims stay open.

Comment: And with "ordered by top 5 days for each month" you mean that you want to show the five days with the highest count per month, correct? What to do in case of ties, e.g. counts 200, 190, 180, 170, 160, 160, 150? Show six records? Four? Or five with one of the 160s arbitrarily chosen?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes at both questions, sorry if i wasnt that clear, thank you.

Comment: So per day you want to count how many claimes were opened and then show the five dates per month with the highest counts. But the accepted answer doesn't give you only the top 5 dates per month. (For this is the difficult part, especially in MySQL.) And you haven't answered what to do in the case of a tie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT OpeningDate, COUNT(OpeningDate)
FROM claim
WHERE LEFT(OpeningDate, 4) = '2017'
GROUP BY OpeningDate
ORDER BY OpeningDate ASC, COUNT(OpeningDate) DESC
```

Comment: I will only add SELECT OpeningDate, COUNT(OpeningDate)
FROM claim where left (OpeningDate, 4) = 2017
GROUP BY OpeningDate
ORDER BY OpeningDate ASC, COUNT(OpeningDate) DESC

Comment: Added your clause :)

Answer (score 0):

You need group by:

```
select OpeningDate,count(1) from your_table group by OpeningDate
```

For top 5, you need `order by` and `limit`

```
select OpeningDate,count(1) 
from  your_table 
group by OpeningDateorder 
order by 2 desc 
limit 5
```

Comment: First works, but for top five it gives me the top five days with the maximum claim files opened per day from the entire year, I needed the top five days from each month with the most claim files opened, but is ok, I will export them into a excel and group them there. Thank you